Facebook intentando usar la Graph API
estoy intentando conectarme a la api de facebook para realizar publicaciones en mi pagina de facebook pero me sale este error:
403
{"error":{"message":"(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\n          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AaCsHXREaekgVWZVge_T_8X"}}```

en el explorador de la api graph le di todos los permisos a mi app:

email
manage_fundraisers
read_insights
publish_video
catalog_management
pages_manage_cta
pages_manage_instant_articles
pages_show_list
read_page_mailboxes
ads_management
ads_read
business_management
pages_messaging
pages_messaging_subscriptions
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_content_publish
leads_retrieval
whatsapp_business_management
instagram_manage_messages
page_events
commerce_account_read_settings
commerce_account_manage_orders
commerce_account_read_orders
commerce_account_read_reports
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
whatsapp_business_messaging
instagram_shopping_tag_products
instagram_branded_content_brand
instagram_branded_content_creator
instagram_branded_content_ads_brand
instagram_manage_events
manage_app_solution

y este es mi codigo de python:
page_access_token = ""

page_id = ""
message = 'mensaje de prueba'

url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{page_id}/feed"

params = {
    'acces_token': page_access_token,
    'message' : message
}

response = requests.post(url, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Publicación realizada con éxito")
    print(response.json())
else:
    print(f"Error al realizar la publicación: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text) 

no se si es configuracion a la hora de crear la app en facebook para desarrolladores o estoy generando mal el token o porque me sale ese error si ya tengo todos los permisos y tengo el perfil de administrador, si a alguien le paso algo igual me podria ayudar
